# Finding filenames that end in a specific character with or without an extension

Tags: grep, find, ls, wildcards

I have a bunch of files in a folder that all end in a different version number, like 1, 2, 3, etc. Some of them have extensions, some of them don't. Is there any way I could use a command like ls, find, or grep that can list all of the files that end in a specific character, like '1', that may or may not end in an extension?

For example, in a directory, I have the following files: `ver1.txt`, `ver1`, and `file.1`. I'd want to do something that would return `ver1.txt` and `ver1`, but not `file.1`, if that helps any. I've tried using something like `ls *[1.]*` but that's not doing what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure `find`:

```
find . -regex '\.[^.]*1\|.*1\.[^.]*'
```

This will match `ver1` and `ver1.txt` and `file1.ver1.txt`, but **not** `file1.ver2.txt`. If you want to match that too:

```
find . -regex '\.[^.]*1\|.*1\..*'
```

You must run these commands inside searched directory, `find somepath ...` whouldn't work, as regex match whole path.

Comment: **pure find** prints: `find: Bad Option: '-regex'.`

Comment: @schily there are many `find` variants, not 100% compatible with each other. Most popular is gnu find and regex is available there.

Comment: A pure find is a find that implements POSIX compliance - not more. Whether `gfind` is most popular iss disputable since embedded Linux platforms come with `busybox` and a `fake find` implementatoion.

Answer (score 1):

As it isn't possible for you to give an example of every filename that could ever exist and every pattern that you could ever search for, I'll go on what you have:

```
find . -type f | awk -F / '{print $2}' | grep -v '\.[1-100]$'
```

Considering that you've given `ver1.txt`, `ver1`, and `file.1` as the files in the directory where you are searching, the above command will return your desired output:

```
ver1.txt
ver1
```

To explain each part:

`find . -type f` Returns every file in the current directory

`awk -F / '{print $2}'` Removes the `./` at the beginning of each file appearing from the `find` command

`grep -v '\.[1-100]$'` Returns any files not ending in `.#` where `#` is any number from `1-100`. The `v` switch finds any lines not matching `.#` In the case of the example you've given, it's necessary to use `\` to escape the `.` and to use single quotes around the string. The `$` indicates files ending with that string although in your case, it will work without it. I only included it in case there may be files that have a `.` somewhere else in the filename.

You'll have to change the parameters depending on what you're looking for but that should get you started.